# Using Boost Library in Visual Studio Code with Code Runner

Tags: c++, boost, vscode-code-runner

I have the program Ex_04.cpp which has this code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>

#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS


namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int write_to_file()
{
    const auto dir = "Test.txt";
    fs::path pp{dir};
    try{
        if( create_directory(pp) ){
            rename(pp, dir);
        }
    }catch(fs::filesystem_error &e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++  -L'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\lib' -I'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\include\\boost-1_81' -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o $fileNameWithoutExt *.cpp  && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
    },
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "googletest.failed",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#f00"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "googletest.passed",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0f0"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "googletest.run",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0f0"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have not changed the files tasks.json, launch.json and c_cpp_properties.json.
The error I get when I try to compile is:

> C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\tvmendes\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1GfM0X.o:Ex_04.cpp:
>     (.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem16create_directoryERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem16create_directoryERKNS0_4pathE]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const*, boost::system::error_code*)`
> C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\tvmendes\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1GfM0X.o:Ex_04.cpp:
>     (.text$*ZN5boost10filesystem6renameERKNS0_4pathES3*[*ZN5boost10filesystem6renameERKNS0_4pathES3*]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::rename(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)`
> C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\tvmendes\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1GfM0X.o:Ex_04.cpp:
>     (.text$_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path9assign_opclIcEEvPKT_S6_PKSt7codecvtIwciE[_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path9assign_opclIcEEvPKT_S6_PKSt7codecvtIwciE]+0x44): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>,  std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const*)`
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried to change the settings.json file by adding the flag -l like this:

`"cd $dir && g++  -L'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\lib' -I'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\include\\boost-1_81'  -l'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\lib' -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o $fileNameWithoutExt *.cpp  && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"`

to link the library filesystem but I always get the error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\boost_1_81_0\boost_installed\lib: Invalid argument
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked and the filesystem library exists at that directory.

My operation system is Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: You're compiling and linking all .cpp files (`*.cpp`) together.

Comment: I would worry about the multiply defined `main` before you worry about the boost library.

Comment: Your other error (in settings.json) is because you should be saying `-L` for the library directory not `-l`. `-l` is for the names of individual libraries.

Comment: In fact looking at your settings you seem to be specifying the library directory twice, once with `-L` and once with `-l`. You should not to do that, for a library directory only `-L` is needed.

Comment: @john The error was incorrect. I have just updated it and the multiply defined main issue is now gone.

Comment: @john My understanding is that -L is for library directory and -l is for defining which libraries will be used for linking. In the settings.json i only use `-L` and `-I` flags.

Comment: @molbdnilo How can i change the compilation line then ?

Comment: @TiagoMendes Your understanding is correct, but your settings.json above clearly has `-l'C:\\boost_1_81_0\\boost_installed\\lib'` which is incorrect. (Which is what the error message is telling you).

Comment: @TiagoMendes There's some confusion here with upper and lower case, but `-I` is for directories to search for header files, `-L` is for directories to search for libraries and `-l` is for the names of the libraries to link. It's this last part that you seem to be missing or have got incorrect.

Comment: @TiagoMendes If I knew I tell you what the setting for `-l` should be but I've never used boost with MinGW, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

Firstly, don't `*.cpp` unless your files are intended to be linked together (they can't if multiple contain `main`).

Second, you were indicating library *path* (`-L`), but failed to link to a specific library *from that path*. Add `-lboost_filesystem`.

When you do, make sure it comes last on the command line.

Finally, you must make sure that the libraries are found at runtime too. The easiest way is to us `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but you can consider `rpath` linker options too.

```
 "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++  -L'/home/sehe/custom/superboost/stage/lib' -I'/home/sehe/custom/superboost' -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread  && LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/sehe/custom/superboost/stage/lib' ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
}
```

See it live:

[image]

### Side Note

As you can see I [re]moved the

```
 #define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
 #undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
```

If you use defines like this:

- define them everywhere (the `#undef` is very suspect)
- define them before the inclusion of any Boost header!

Failing to do so will violate [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: Hi @sehe, I followed your instructions and i got this errors:
`C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_thread: No such file or directory`

Comment: My lib directory is `C:\boost_1_81_0\boost_installed\lib` and has only files like this `libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_81.lib` and a cmake folder.

Comment: Okay. You didn't exactly specify which libraries (_"Using Boost Library in Visual Studio Code with Code Runner"_) so I gave a subset of common libraries you will typically use. If you only have `filesystem`, drop the other two, of course (or build the rest as well)

Comment: Sorry @sehe, what i meant is that my lib folder has files of the type ´*.lib´.

Comment: Depending on whether those are static libraries or only import libraries you can link them (e.g. using the filename like `libboost_filesystem.lib` instead of `boost_filesystem`). There may also be a CMake way to use statically linked libraries, but I'd try this to see whether your build is even complete - it looks like it may not be.